# Turn on/off TV using HDMI CEC android

Tags: android, android-tv, television, hdmi

I haven't use hdmi cec. Now I want to use in my app. With the help of app I want to turn on and off TV using HDMI Cec Controller but not able to find any proper code snippet that help me to achieve the same. So if any one have a idea let me know how to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This HDMI CEC controller, in the Android Framework is a system level API. 
So better search on "how to use system apis in android studio?", there are few workarounds to do the same. 
eg: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Other dependencies that you will find along the way: 
 1. Sink and source device to have updated commands in devices.mk file. Sink means the TV/Output unit and the source will be the OTT box/Android system. 
 2. Not all device will be compatible with this. 
 3. You need CEC enabled on both the devices.